# Adding fields to the new contact option when part of a lookup on a custom console layout

Tags: console, service

[image]

Hi,

I have created a custom console within service cloud and set the 'Contact Role' as one of the components using a lookup to contact name,

This works fine and allows me to create a new user from within my case.

However we have a custom object called 'sites' (this is basically a ship to location - our accounts are our customers).

On a contact i have a record called Site Contact For - and here i can link the contact to a head office (account) via the account link and then also link them to a site (Ship to location) using the Site Contact for field.

I want to be able to link the contact to the site from this lookup object but cannot work out how to add additional fields into the Contact box on the right hand side...

Any ideas - i have looked at the search view, mini page layouts etc but seem to be missing something,

Kind Regards

Matt

Answer (score 2):

From setup, click `Customize > Contacts > Page Layouts` and then click on Edit next to the `Contact (Support) Layout` which is the one that's used by Cases. I believe that should be what you're looking for. From your description, the field you mention won't be available on the general Cases page layout, instead only on the Contact page layout for Cases.

Comment: Thanks for your respone - i have looked at the page layout and can add the 'Sites' option as a mobile card - for use with SF1 but i cannot see where i would add it

Basically on the right hand side of my image i have the option to create a new Contact, Here i can link the contact to an account but need to be able to link them to a site as well... i cannot find the option anywhere

Comment: I see where `Site` is listed directly underneath `Account Name` in your Case Page Layout. It would seem that perhaps your best option would be to populate that field if it's not available on your Contact Support Page Layout. It's either that or you may need to create a custom component that includes it. I don't know what else to tell you since it appears to be more closely related to Account (perhaps a M-D?) than to Contact. I don't even see where you've added an address field. If you did, you could try using the Site Address for it using a lookup.